# Why header is not passing a string upon a submit?

Tags: php

I have a textBox where the user must fill his email, like this:

```
<td><input type="email" name="MAIL" value="foo@gmail.com" required></td>
```

And a submit button, where runs the following code when the user presses it:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    header("Location: page.php?email=".$_REQUEST["email"]."");
}
```

I was expecting that upon a submit click the following page was:

```
page.php?email=foo@gmail.com // What I should expect!
```

But I get always:

```
page.php?email=    //what I get...Wrong!
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your code. The `name` of the element is "MAIL" but you are pulling "email" from the REQUEST.

Try this:

```
<td><input type="email" name="MAIL" value="foo@gmail.com" required></td>
```

then

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    header("Location: page.php?email=".$_REQUEST["MAIL"]."");
}
```

Comment: you're right!! thank you!